# Is there any way to send information to be stored in a webbased database(eg. sql) from an external application?

Tags: html, sql, http, posting

I'm trying to create a server list using a webAPI that passes through information about each server(IP/domain) in its database. The idea is that each server would send this information to the database upon initialization. What would be the most efficient way of achieving this relationship?

Comment: Pretty simple I think. 1. Store **some** `connection string` details in your `appsettings` or `webconfig` and then pull that data out when you need it. 2. Using that data connect to the DB. 3. Get the server to push through it's relevant details to an existing table in the DB. 4. Close connection.

Comment: Please consider uploading some example code or some examples of what you've tried alreaedy. I fear you're going to get downvoted/flagged however, as this is a broad question with no examples. If you have no examples, consider posting on Quora instead for a better answer!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll try Quora.